# initializationError using MockUp Test Case

Tags: java, mockito, mockups

I am getting the following error in BannerUpdatedBoltTest when trying to add a mockupTest case in Another Class :TagLevelDataBoltTest.
I tried to add the MockUp testcase in @Before as well but it gives me the same error. Any idea why ?

Test Case :

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        new MockUp<TagImpl>() {
            @Mock
            public String getSinglePrimaryColor() {
                return  "Grey";

            }
        };
        conf.put(HConstants.ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM + "." + HBaseConnectionPool.CATALOG_POOL, "");
        conf.put(AbstractBolt.MAX_TAG_COUNT_DOCS_PROPERTY, Integer.toString(2));
        conf.put(AbstractBolt.NO_TAG_COUNT_FOR_PTITLE_DOC_PROPERTY, Integer.toString(2));
        Config.init(conf);
    }
```

TagLevelDataBoltTest.java

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest(SellerProgram.class)
    public class TagLevelDataBoltTest extends AbstractBoltTest {
        private static Map<String, String> conf = new HashMap<String, String>();
        private TagLevelDataBolt bolt = new TagLevelDataBolt();
        private Map<String, String> expectedFieldValueMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        private Map<String, String> inputFieldValueMapToBolt = new HashMap<String, String>();
        private Map<String, String> storedFieldValueMapToBolt = new HashMap<String, String>();
        private ProductTitleEvent event = new ProductTitleEvent(this.ptitleId, Action.UPDATE, null);

        private HBaseTagDao tagDao = Mockito.mock(HBaseTagDao.class);
        private HbasePdirNodeDao pdirNodeDao = Mockito.mock(HbasePdirNodeDao.class);
        private HBaseGlobalModelDao globalModelDao = Mockito.mock(HBaseGlobalModelDao.class);

        @BeforeClass
        public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
new MockUp<TagImpl>() {
            @Mock
            public String getSinglePrimaryColor() {
                return  "Grey";

            }
        };
            conf.put(HConstants.ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM + "." + HBaseConnectionPool.CATALOG_POOL, "");
            conf.put(AbstractBolt.MAX_TAG_COUNT_DOCS_PROPERTY, Integer.toString(2));
            conf.put(AbstractBolt.NO_TAG_COUNT_FOR_PTITLE_DOC_PROPERTY, Integer.toString(2));
            Config.init(conf);
        }

        @AfterClass
        public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
            Config.clear();
        }

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws IOException {
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(SellerProgram.class);
            Mockito.when(SellerProgram.getCPCInfo(SellerProgram.SELLER_GROUP_PROGRAM_ID, 4825235L)).thenReturn(getCPCInfo());

            Mockito.when(tagDao.getActiveTagsByPtitleId(989417179L)).thenReturn(getTags());
            Mockito.when(pdirNodeDao.get(98760003L)).thenReturn(getPdirNode98760003());
            Mockito.when(globalModelDao.getVariantData(1010234L, "us", 989417179L, 1146662679L)).thenReturn(getTagVariantData(1146662679L));
            Mockito.when(globalModelDao.getVariantData(1010234L, "us", 989417179L, 1145602023L)).thenReturn(getTagVariantData(1145602023L));

            this.bolt.tagDao = this.tagDao;
            this.bolt.pdirNodeDao = this.pdirNodeDao;
            this.bolt.globalModelDao = this.globalModelDao;
            this.bolt.groupSeparator = ",";
            this.bolt.market = "us";
            this.bolt.init();
        }

        @Test
        public void testPtitleLevelField() throws Exception {
            inputFieldValueMapToBolt.put(SolrIndexTableConst.TAG_SUMMARY.getColumnName(), "1.0|2014-12-31 23:59:59.9|1972900427|1145602023,2576883,25,99.99,0,2880,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-2,0,-2,0,-,0,0|1146662679,4825235,25,99.99,0,2880,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-2,0,-2,0,-,0,0");
            inputFieldValueMapToBolt.put(SolrIndexTableConst.SELLER_DATA_SOURCE.getColumnName(), "{}");
            inputFieldValueMapToBolt.put(SolrIndexTableConst.MODEL_ID.getColumnName(), "1010234");
            inputFieldValueMapToBolt.put(SolrIndexTableConst.NODE_IDS.getColumnName(), "98760003");
            inputFieldValueMapToBolt.put(SolrIndexTableConst.LEAF_NODE_IDS.getColumnName(), "98760003");
            expectedFieldValueMap.put(SolrIndexTableConst.TAG_ID.getColumnName(), "1146662679 1145602023");
            expectedFieldValueMap.put(SolrIndexTableConst.TAG_NAME.getColumnName(), "{\"1145602023\":\"NEW Ancient Minerals PURE Ultra Magnesium Oil Spray with OPT MSM - 8oz Bottle\",\"1146662679\":\"Ancient Minerals Ultra Pure with MSM 8 Oz\"}");
            //expectedFieldValueMap.put(SolrIndexTableConst.TAG_DESCRIPTION.getColumnName(), "{\"1145602023\":\"Ancient Minerals\",\"1146662679\":\"Ancient Minerals Magnesium Oil Ultra with OptiMSM by LL Magnetic Clay is a rapidly absorbed ultra pure and concentrated easy topical spray that incorporates the unique synergistic benefits of MSM and magnesium. MSM has long been revered as a superior form of sulfur supplementation, but as a topical it enhances cell membrane permeability and may facilitate more efficient uptake of magnesium ions. Ancient Minerals Magnesium Oil Ultra contains approximately 1.6g elemental magnesium and 3.6g of MSM (OptiMSM) per fl oz. Ancient Minerals Magnesium Oil Ultra utilizes premium distilled OptiMSM, the worlds purity standard for MSM. Ancient Minerals ultra pure magnesium oil is extracted from the Ancient Zechstein Seabed in Europe, 1600 to 2000 meters deep in the interior of the Earth. Well protected for the last 250 million years, it is the most pure magnesium oil in the world and a mark of purity on every bottle of Ancient Minerals. Magnesium oil is not actually an oil but was named that because it has an oil-like texture due to a high saturation of magnesium chloride in water. Possible Benefits of Ancient Minerals Magnesium Oil: Support for restoring cellular magnesium levels* Provides cellular protecting support* Supports detoxification* Support for relieving aches and pains* Support for improving mood and relieving stress* Encourages healthy skin tissue* For the amazing benefits of Genuine Zechstein magnesium, try Ancient Minerals Magnesium Oil Ultra today!\"}");
            expectedFieldValueMap.put(SolrIndexTableConst.TAG_EAN.getColumnName(), "{\"1145602023\":\"EAN 2\",\"1146662679\":\"EAN 1\"}");
            expectedFieldValueMap.put(SolrIndexTableConst.TAG_MFR_PART_NO.getColumnName(), "{\"1145602023\":\"MFR 2\",\"1146662679\":\"MFR 1\"}");
            expectedFieldValueMap.put(SolrIndexTableConst.TAG_SUMMARY.getColumnName(), "1.0|2014-12-31 23:59:59.9|1972900427|1145602023,2576883,25,99.99,0,2880,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-2,0,-2,0,-,0,0|1146662679,4825235,25,99.99,0,2880,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-2,0,-2,0,-,0,0");
            //expectedFieldValueMap.put(SolrIndexTableConst.TAG_NLA.getColumnName(), "{\"1145602023\":[\"image_color~Grey\"]}");
            expectedFieldValueMap.put(SolrIndexTableConst.TAXONOMY_IDS.getColumnName(), "{\"1145602023\":22345,\"1146662679\":12345}");
            expectedFieldValueMap.put(SolrIndexTableConst.SELLER_TAG_RANK.getColumnName(), "{\"1145602023\":2222,\"1146662679\":1111}");
            expectedFieldValueMap.put(SolrIndexTableConst.SELLER_GROUP.getColumnName(),"{\"1146662679\":[\"8888\",\"6060\"]}");
            expectedFieldValueMap.put(SolrIndexTableConst.MODEL_KEY.getColumnName(),"{\"1145602023\":\"1010234``color:white~hinge side:right\",\"1146662679\":\"1010234``color:silver~hinge side:left\"}");
            compareFieldsValue(expectedFieldValueMap, this.bolt.process(this.event, inputFieldValueMapToBolt, storedFieldValueMapToBolt));
        }

    }
```

This is Error in receiving :

```
initializationError(com.nextag.build.index.product.bolt.BannerUpdatedBoltTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.getEntry(ThreadLocal.java:376)
            at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.access$000(ThreadLocal.java:261)
            at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:146)
            at mockit.internal.mockups.MockState.update(MockState.java:54)
            at mockit.internal.mockups.MockStates.updateMockState(MockStates.java:93)
            at mockit.internal.state.TestRun.updateMockState(TestRun.java:160)
            at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java)
            at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.MockFrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(MockFrameworkMethod.java:46)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invokeWithCheckedThrows(MethodReflection.java:106)
            at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.callMock(MockMethodBridge.java:85)
            at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.invoke(MockMethodBridge.java:44)
            at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java)
            at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.MockFrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(MockFrameworkMethod.java:46)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invokeWithCheckedThrows(MethodReflection.java:106)
            at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.callMock(MockMethodBridge.java:85)
            at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.invoke(MockMethodBridge.java:44)
            at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java)
            at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.MockFrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(MockFrameworkMethod.java:46)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invokeWithCheckedThrows(MethodReflection.java:106)
            at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.callMock(MockMethodBridge.java:85)
            at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.invoke(MockMethodBridge.java:44)
            at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java)
            at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.MockFrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(MockFrameworkMethod.java:46)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invokeWithCheckedThrows(MethodReflection.java:106)
            at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.callMock(MockMethodBridge.java:85)
            at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.invoke(MockMethodBridge.java:44)
            at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invokeWithCheckedThrows(MethodReflection.java:106)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.callMock(MockMethodBridge.java:85)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.invoke(MockMethodBridge.java:44)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java)
        at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.MockFrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(MockFrameworkMethod.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invokeWithCheckedThrows(MethodReflection.java:106)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.callMock(MockMethodBridge.java:85)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.invoke(MockMethodBridge.java:44)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java)
        at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.MockFrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(MockFrameworkMethod.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invokeWithCheckedThrows(MethodReflection.java:106)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.callMock(MockMethodBridge.java:85)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.invoke(MockMethodBridge.java:44)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java)
        at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.MockFrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(MockFrameworkMethod.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invokeWithCheckedThrows(MethodReflection.java:106)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.callMock(MockMethodBridge.java:85)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.invoke(MockMethodBridge.java:44)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java)
        at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.MockFrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(MockFrameworkMethod.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invokeWithCheckedThrows(MethodReflection.java:106)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.callMock(MockMethodBridge.java:85)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.invoke(MockMethodBridge.java:44)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java)
 at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.MockFrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(MockFrameworkMethod.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invokeWithCheckedThrows(MethodReflection.java:106)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.callMock(MockMethodBridge.java:85)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.invoke(MockMethodBridge.java:44)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java)
        at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.MockFrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(MockFrameworkMethod.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invokeWithCheckedThrows(MethodReflection.java:106)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.callMock(MockMethodBridge.java:85)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.invoke(MockMethodBridge.java:44)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVo
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below in setup() -

```
@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

The initMocks method is called to initialize annotated objects.
Hope this help.